# iPad enter key on keyboard for joining WiFi network

Tags: wifi, ipad

I just received an iPad from Apple. I have entered my password for joining the network, but cannot find the enter key. How does one access the enter key on the iPad keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a <kbd>Join</kbd> key on the right of the keyboard. That's the enter key for joining the network.

On touch keyboards, it's possible to re-label the keys in order to match better the behavior of the key to the specific application or context. When hitting enter in the WiFi connection panel it's synonymous to trying to join the WiFi network.